# Django ORM, get data

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How to get the top 10 users, whose question with most answers? I did it by using 2 requests to db, but I need in one request, if possible.
P.S. I'm using MySQL, there is no 'distinct'

Result format:

```
User.username | Question.id | number of comments
```

I have the models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(models.Model):
   header = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
   view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   content = models.TextField()
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Answer(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   content = models.TextField()
```

My realization with 2 requests:

```
def select5():
    print 'SELECT 5'
    N = 10
    top_n_questions = Answer.objects.all().values('question').annotate(ans_count=Count('question')).order_by('ans_count').reverse()[:N]
    top_n_questions_id = []
    top_n_questions_rate = []
    top_n_users = []
    print top_n_questions

    for dic in top_n_questions:
        top_n_questions_id.append(dic['question'])
        top_n_questions_rate.append(dic['ans_count'])

    top_n_questions = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=top_n_questions_id)

    for question in top_n_questions:
        top_n_users.append(question.author)

    for i in range(N):
        print '%s question id: %d, rate: %d' % (top_n_users[i].username,\
            top_n_questions_id[i], top_n_questions_rate[i])
```

**UPD: I found how to do it:**

```
def select6():
    print 'SELECT 6'
    print 'bla-bla-bla'
    top_questions = Question.objects.annotate(answers=Count('answer')).order_by('-answers').select_related('author')[:10]
    for question in top_questions:
        print '%s question id: %d, rate: %d' % (question.author, question.id, question.answers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) By logic you need something like that below (but I think it will work **only** if question with user has one_to_one relation), so I think it doesn't work, but you can try it =) :

```
top_users = User.objects.annotate(ans_count=Count('question_set__answer_set')).order_by('-ans_count')[:10]
```

2) Solution that I suggest (I think is not best, but simple one) is additional field `answer_count` in `Question` that store count of answer so I can sort or filter by that value. This field updates after every `Answer.objects.create()` by post save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Answer)
def update_answer_count(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    question = instance.question
    question.answer_count = sender.objects.filter(question=question).count()
    question.save(update_fields=['answer_count'])
```

so after this you can do:

```
top_users = User.objects.order_by('-question_set__answer_count')[:10]
```

and in your template:

```
{% for user in top_users %}
    {% for question in user.question_set.all %}
        {{ user.username }}
        {{ question.id }}
        {{ question.answer_count }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Laravel's ORM

```
User::orderBy('answers', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

something like this mate but for DJango!

```
Entry.objects.all().order_by('answers')[:5]
```